# Using bash to copy file to spec folders

Tags: linux, bash

I have a folder with a fair amount of subfolders. In some of the subfolders do I have a folder.jpg picture. What I try to do find that folder(s) and copy it to all other subfolders that got the same artist and album information then continue on to the next album etc.

The structure of all the folders are "`artist - year - album - [encoding information]`". 
I have made a really simple one liner that find the folders that got the file but there am I stuck.

```
ls -F | grep / | while read folders;do find "$folders" -name folder.jpg; done
```

Anyone have any good tip or ideas how to solve this or pointers how to proceed?

Edit:

First of all, i´m real new to this (like you cant  tell) so please have patience.

Ok, let me break it down even more.

I have a folder structure that looks like this:

```
artist1 - year - album - [flac]
artist1 - year - album - [mp3]
artist1 - year - album - [AAC]
artist2 - year - album - [flac]
etc
```

I like to loop over the set of folders that have the same artist and album information and look for a `folder.jpg` file. When I find that file do I like to copy it to all of the other folders in the same set.

Ex if I find one `folder.jpg` in `artist1 - year - album - [flac]` folder do I like to have that `folder.jpg` copied to `artist1 - year - album - [mp3]` &
`artist1 - year - album - [AAC]` but not to artist2 - year - album - [flac].

The continue the loop until all the sets been processed. I really hope that makes it a bit more easy to understand what I try to do :)

Comment: Is there always only one subfolder with folder.jpg? What should be happen if there are more than one folder.jpg? Do you wan't to keep originals or don't care?

Comment: There can be more then one folder.jpg but I dont care to keep any 'originals' as long as the one writing over it are from the same 'set' (artist - album). 

The importance/idea of the script is that not the wrong folder.jpg gets copied to the wrong folder set and that all folders get a copy of the correct folder.jpg. Does that make any sense?

Comment: Wouldn't simple `find . -name folder.jpg` be enough? Seems to me that you complicate things... Also, an example of "having these and these folders, while these have folders.jpg and others don't, I want .... to happen" would be nice, since I don't understand what you really want to.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. I have updated the original post with some more information, hope that will help some :)

Comment: You could use the `cut` command to extract the common part of the directory name.

Comment: here's a [Python script](http://www.stypi.com/jfs1/move-folder-jpg) that solves a slightly more complex problem (it doesn't assume that all (artist,album) directories are in the same directory) (not tested)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know its not the most efficient or correct code, but this did the job for me and I got the correct folder.jpg in the right folders.

```
IFS='
'

source=( `find . -name folder.jpg |  sed 's/^..//' | sort -u` )
   for s in ${source[@]}
        do

          fullname=(`echo $s | cut -d'/' -f1 | sort -u`)
          checkname=`echo $fullname | cut -d'[' -f1 | sort -u`
          match=( `find . -name "$checkname*" | sed 's/^..//' | sort -u` )

             for a in ${match[@]}
                do
                    if [[ "$a" == "$fullname" ]];
                    then
                        echo $a 'not copied'
                    else
                        echo $a
                        #echo $match '*M*'
                        cp $s "$a/folder.jpg"

                    fi    
                done


    done
```

Answer (score 1):

```
IFS='
'
FLDRS=`find . -name folder.jpg | grep -v ./folder.jpg | sed -e 's@/folder\.jpg$@@`
for F in $FLDRS; do
  NOENC=`echo "$F" | sed -e 's/\[.*$//'`
  for DST in "$NOENC*"; do
    if [ -d "$DST" -a ! -f "$DST/folder.jpg" ]; then
      cp "$F/folder.jpg" "$DST"
    fi
  done
done
```

It is inefficient for sets which contain folder.jpg in all encondings already, but unless there is an error it should do the work.

Comment: If it won't I hope you can fix it yourself - it's small enough to understand it.

Comment: J.F.Sebastian - the example did not show such possibility :-) and I think it would be crazy organization to have them scattered over. Franko knows if it can happen or same album dirs are guaranteed to be siblings.

Comment: IFS takes care of it, along with quoting every variable-containing file name.

Comment: @herby: I've missed it. Why don't you write it as `IFS="\n"`?

Comment: I have now tested it and getting an 

`command substitution: line 3: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `''` and
`command substitution: line 4: syntax error: unexpected end of file
`

I guess its a missing ' after `'s@/folder\.jpg$@@`, but even if adding that makes the script run, are no folder.jpg copied. 

But I like the example. Will hopefully give me more insight how to build shell scripts for this kind of tasks in the future.

Comment: @Sebastian: Because that does not work. "\n" to the shell means "n" (escaped n). You need a hard newline.

Comment: @Franko: Yes, sorry. If it still does not work, I can't tell why now (I just written it, not tested). You could add some echos into the script to show the actual values of the vars and to track if it actually loops... hopefully you get it working somehow.

Comment: I will see if I can understand it and correct it to work. Guess I have to start with read up on sed commands.

Anyway, thank you for you help. Much appreciated!

Comment: Well here it only 1 command used in both cases (substitute) and in both cases it substituted something for nothing (that is, deleted it). Otherwise only tricky part is the condition in the if, I presume. Good luck!

Comment: A bit surprised that 

`FLDRS=`find . -name folder.jpg | grep -v ./folder.jpg`
echo $FLDRS`

gives an empty print out. Is that correct?

Comment: @bos: It works (in a sense that files with spaces in them are fine, but you're right it doesn't recognize `\n` as  a newline). After doing `echo -n $IFS`, `echo -n \'$IFS\'`, and `echo -n "$IFS"` I understand why some might not like programming  in bash.

Comment: @Franko: Maybe your grep is eagerly interpreting ./folder.jpg as regexp not a plain string, thus grepping out every line :-/ From my experience only grep -E / egrep should behave like this. If you can guarantee that you won't have folder.jpg in the main folder, you can just omit it; or go man find and look for min-depth or something similar and set it to 1; this way you can omit the grep as well. It was there purely to filter out ./folder.jpg, that is folder.jpg from main directory. Another possibility is to `grep -E -v '^\.folders\.jpg$'`, using the regexps directly.